# A faster alternative to bind_rows

Tags: r, dplyr

As we know, `dplyr's` functions are fairly efficient. However, I find myself in a situation where using `bind_rows` on an extremely large list of data frames takes much longer than I'd like. Does anyone know of a faster alternative?

Comment: `data.table::rbindlist()`?

Comment: would rbind() work?!

Comment: @27ϕ9 It's amazing how sometimes the simplest solutions elude me. Put that as an answer and I'll be more than happy to mark it as the best answer.

Comment: @user12256545 just try something like this, with a big list: `microbenchmark::microbenchmark(data.table::rbindlist(listed), do.call(rbind, listed), dplyr::bind_rows(listed) )`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dataframe::rbindlist()` [per @s__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64753356/a-faster-alternative-to-bind-rows/74030032#comment114490435_64753356)